# Relation between PoolTimeout, IdleTimeout & IdleCheckFrequency in go-redis

Tags: go, redis

Can someone let me know the relation between [PoolTimeout](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/854c88a72c8bb9c09936145aef886b7697d6b995/options.go#L54), [IdleTimeout](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/854c88a72c8bb9c09936145aef886b7697d6b995/options.go#L58) & [IdleCheckFrequency](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/854c88a72c8bb9c09936145aef886b7697d6b995/options.go#L62) in [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis)?

Doubts:-

1. If I specify `PoolTimeout` 20ms, `IdleTimeout` 20ms, `PoolSize` 100 & `IdleCheckFrequency` 1 min. Let's say all the connection in the pool are used and a connection finishes its operation. Then will the request for a new connection wait till the IdleCheck is run in 1 min interval?
2. If I specify `PoolSize` 100 will the client keep open 100 connections to redis even if there is no active client operation being performed to Redis?

Environment:-

1. Go - 1.7.4
2. Redis - 3.2.6
3. Go-Redis - v5.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been answered in github [here](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/issues/441). Just posting the relevant parts below:-

> PoolSize limits max number of open connections. If app is idle then
> go-redis does not open any connections.
>
> New connection is opened when there is a command to process and there
> are no idle connections in the pool. Idle connections are closed after
> they are idle for IdleTimeout.
>
> IdleCheckFrequency specifies how often we check if connection is
> expired. This is needed in case app is idle and there is no activity.
> Normally idle connections are closed when go-redis asks pool for a
> (healthy) connection.